# Why Spark SQL translates String "null" to Object null for Float/Double types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing `float` and `double` values.

```
scala> val df = List((Float.NaN, Double.NaN), (1f, 0d)).toDF("x", "y")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: float, y: double]

scala> df.show
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|NaN|NaN|
|1.0|0.0|
+---+---+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- x: float (nullable = false)
 |-- y: double (nullable = false)
```

When I replace `NaN` values with `null` value, I gave `null` as String to the Map in `fill` operation.

```
scala> val map = df.columns.map((_, "null")).toMap
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(x -> null, y -> null)

scala> df.na.fill(map).printSchema
root
 |-- x: float (nullable = true)
 |-- y: double (nullable = true)


scala> df.na.fill(map).show
+----+----+
|   x|   y|
+----+----+
|null|null|
| 1.0| 0.0|
+----+----+
```

And I got correct value. But I was not able to understand as to How/Why Spark SQL is translating `null` as a String to a `null` object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked in to the `fill` function in `Dataset`, It checks the datatype and tries to convert to datatype of its column's schema. If it can be converted then it converts otherwise it returns null.

It does not convert to "`null`" to object `null` but it returns null if exception occurs while converting.

```
val map = df.columns.map((_, "WHATEVER")).toMap
```

gives null

```
and val map = df.columns.map((_, "9999.99")).toMap
```

gives 9999.99

If you want to update the `NAN` with same datatype, you can get result as expected.

Hope this helps you to understand!

Answer (score 1):

It's not that "null" as a String translates to a `null` object. You can try using the transformation with any String and still get `null` (with the exception of strings that can directly be cast to double/float, see below). For example, using

```
val map = df.columns.map((_, "abc")).toMap
```

would give the same result. My guess is that as the columns are of type `float` and `double` converting the `NaN` values to a string will give `null`. Using a number instead would work as expected, e.g.

```
val map = df.columns.map((_, 1)).toMap
```

As some strings can directly be cast to `double` or `float` those are also possible to use in this case.

```
val map = df.columns.map((_, "1")).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the source-code, in `fill` your string is casted to a double/float:

```
private def fillCol[T](col: StructField, replacement: T): Column = {
    col.dataType match {
      case DoubleType | FloatType =>
        coalesce(nanvl(df.col("`" + col.name + "`"), lit(null)),
          lit(replacement).cast(col.dataType)).as(col.name)
      case _ =>
        coalesce(df.col("`" + col.name + "`"), lit(replacement).cast(col.dataType)).as(col.name)
    }
  }
```

The relevant source code for casting is here (similar code for Floats):

Cast.scala (taken from Spark 1.6.3) :

```
  // DoubleConverter
  private[this] def castToDouble(from: DataType): Any => Any = from match {
    case StringType =>
      buildCast[UTF8String](_, s => try s.toString.toDouble catch {
        case _: NumberFormatException => null
      })
    case BooleanType =>
      buildCast[Boolean](_, b => if (b) 1d else 0d)
    case DateType =>
      buildCast[Int](_, d => null)
    case TimestampType =>
      buildCast[Long](_, t => timestampToDouble(t))
    case x: NumericType =>
      b => x.numeric.asInstanceOf[Numeric[Any]].toDouble(b)
  }
```

So Spark trys to convert the `String` to a `Double` (`s.toString.toDouble`), if thats not possible (i.e. you get a `NumberFormatException`) you get a `null`. So instead of `"null"` you could also use `"foo"` witht he same outcome. But if you use `"1.0"` in your map, than `NaNs` and `nulls` will be replaced with `1.0` because the `String` `"1.0"` is indeed parsable to a `Double`.